# coffeescript line number in error.stack?

Tags: coffeescript

Following coffee-script code:

```
try
    any_error_here
catch err
    alert err.stack
```

Gives following stack trace:

```
ReferenceError: any_error_here is not defined 
  at eval (coffeescript:5:3)
```

How to get coffeescript line number for this stack (line 2)?

Here is simple html with same question:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Coffee-script stack trace problems</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://coffeescript.org/extras/coffee-script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="dt_example">
        <script type="text/coffeescript" language="javascript">
    try
        any_error_here
    catch err
        alert err.message+'\n'+err.stack + '\n\nWhat is coffeescript line number for this stack?'
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a problem for [source maps](http://coffeescript.org/#source-maps).

When you compile your CoffeeScript, you can generate a source map by specifying the `-m` option:

`coffee -c -m so.coffee`

In browsers that support source maps (e.g. Chrome), the CoffeeScript file will appear in the **Sources** tab, and errors and log statements will refer to the corresponding line in the CoffeeScript file.

[image: Chrome developer console with source-mapped CoffeeScript]

For more information, check out the [HTML5 tutorial on source maps](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/sourcemaps/), and a [short article about using source maps with CoffeeScript](http://ryanflorence.com/2012/coffeescript-source-maps/).

If you have a source map, you can also use it to parse a stack trace string and refer back to the original uncompiled file as outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24637356/javascript-debug-stack-trace-with-source-maps).